Can you append multiple children onto different lines?
I am wondering if it's possible to append children onto different lines in JavaScript. I am trying to recreate an old Oregon Trail project and am taking a new approach at it, and when I append the existing children they show up directly next to each other. Is there a way to get them to print out on different lines.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Project</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Oregon Trail</h1>
        </div>

        <span id="span"><button id="btn" class="btns">Lantern</button><br>
            <button id="btn1" class="btns">Lantern and butter churn</button><br>
            <button id="btn2" class="btns">Butter churn</button><br>
            <button id="btn3" class="btns">Box</button><br>     
        </span>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

const btnElement = document.getElementById("btn");
const button = document.createElement("btn22");
const button1 = document.createElement("btn23");
button.innerText = "Yes";
button1.innerText = "No";

button.classList.add("btns");
button1.classList.add("btns");

btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.body.appendChild(button1);
})

I haven't tried much other than attaching the child to a string, but nothing has worked and it doesn't look like anyone has had this issue before.

So right now you're appending both elements at the end of <body>. Where is it you actually want to add them? You can always append to the relevant parent element or use something like insertAdjacentElement()

If you want to create some element that takes full row on the page, you should create a block element like div.
Try modifying your script as below code:
const btnElement = document.getElementById("btn");
const button = document.createElement("div"); //creating div for inline
const button1 = document.createElement("div"); //creating div for inline
button.innerText = "Yes";
button1.innerText = "No";

button.classList.add("btns");
button1.classList.add("btns");

btnElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.body.appendChild(button1);
})

Let me know in the comment, if this solution works for you or not. I'm quite sure it will do the job. Cheers!
